# comparison of two Arraylist and Create new Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have two ArrayList a & b both ArrayList size is more then 50000. I want to compare them and remove ArrayList b from a and Add Remaining object into new ArrayList c.

My Code is Here :

```
c = new ArrayList<String>(a);
c.removeAll(b);
```

and i am also try this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    if (!b.contains(a.get(i))) {
        c.add(a.get(i));
    }
}
```

both comparison process is taking lot of time.

How to solve and optimize this problem.

Comment: Do you need to use arraylists, or could you use another container? e.g. a set.

Comment: no i need to use Arraylist only because after create Arralist i need to pass other class and do again comparison process  and show into List view.

Comment: As @khelwood wrote, another container might help you, since both sample codes run in N^2, in this case 50000*50000 comparisons are performed. If you turn at least `b` into a `Set` (for example `HashSet`), `b.contains()` will be constant time, so performance should improve.

Comment: but my second code is same as you want to say in that case my comparisons are performed only 50000 time...

Comment: You should take a look into algorithm and time complexity and realize that comparing 50k objects with another 50k is not a good idea on non indexed / hased data sets.

Comment: thanks luk2302  data set worked faster then Array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfect solution for like this questions

**I have three ArrayList a,b & c**

**ArrayList a size = 25000, b = 20000**

now I want to remove b from a if i'm try to remove one array from second using for loop then i got application stuck issue so here is solution for remove one array from second array :

```
ArrayList<String> A = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> B = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> C;

Set<String> setA = new HashSet<String>(A);
Set<String> setB = new HashSet<String>(B);
setA.removeAll(setB);

c = new ArrayList<String>(setA);
```

Using set you can easily remove array from another array without stuck issue and also process is faster then for loop

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ArrayLists`, try using `SparseArrays`:

**Initialisation:**

When you populate both a & b, instead of doing it this way with `ArrayLists`:

```
String newItem = "sample";
a.add(newItem);
```

Do it like this with `SparseArray`:

```
String newItem = "sample";
a.put(newItem.hashCode(), newItem);
```

Same goes with b.

**Iteration:**

```
// c can still be an array list
ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<String>();
int key;
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    key = a.keyAt(i);
    if (b.indexOfKey == -1)
    {
         c.add(a.get(key));
    }
}
```

Your code performance: `O(|a| * |b|)` or, if `|a| = |b|`, `O(|a|^2)`, meaning that if both a & b have about 50,000 items, there will be a total of 2,500,000,000 iterations (2.5 billion).

This code's performance will be `O(|a|)`, meaning that if a has about 50,000 items, there will be a total of 50,000 iterations.

You should note that while the ***time*** complexity of this method is much better, the ***space*** complexity is a lot worse, since this method allocates much more memory than your method.

Answer (score 0):

```
please try the below example, I think it should resolve your issue

    public static void main(String a[]){

        List a1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List b = new ArrayList<>();
        List c = new ArrayList<>();

        a1.add("1");
        a1.add("2");
        a1.add("3");
        a1.add("4");
        b.add("2");
        b.add("3");
        c.addAll(a1);
        System.out.println("a :::: " + c + " :::: b ::: " + b);
        c.removeAll(b);
        System.out.println("a :::: " + c + " :::: b ::: " + b);
    }
```

Comment: this comparison process is taking lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this.

```
  public static ArrayList<String > getDifference(ArrayList<String>   arraylistprevious,ArrayList<String> arraylistnew) 
  {
     ArrayList<String> temp=null;
        try {



                temp = new ArrayList<String>();
                temp.addAll(arraylistnew);
                temp.removeAll(arraylistprevious);

                System.out.println("temp List: " + temp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }




    return temp;

  }
```